# GRUB failed to install to the following devices error on upgrade

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I'm upgrading an old laptop from 12.04 to 12.10, but during the process I'm getting some errors relating to the grub upgrade. After some Googling I found a suggestion to purge grub and reinstall the packages. On install, this time grub prompted me to choose the install device:

```
GRUB install devices:

    [ ] /dev/sda (64023 MB; TOSHIBA_THNSNC064GMMJ)         
    [ ] /dev/sdb (64023 MB; TOSHIBA_THNSNC064GMMJ)           
    [ ] /dev/dm-5 (35145 MB; isw_bdegajgjcj_Volume0)
```

This machine has a ~35G partition with Ubuntu on, and a larger partition with Windows on. `df` gives me:

```
Filesystem                            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/isw_bdegajgjcj_Volume0p5   33G   24G  7.5G  76% /
udev                                  1.8G   12K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                 726M 1016K  725M   1% /run
none                                  5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                  1.8G  2.2M  1.8G   1% /run/shm
grub-mount                             33G   24G  7.5G  76% /var/lib/os-prober/mount
/dev/mapper/isw_bdegajgjcj_Volume0p3   78G   65G   13G  85% /media/ACAEBDA1AEBD648C
/dev/mapper/isw_bdegajgjcj_Volume0p2  100M   25M   76M  25% /media/System Reserved
```

So I picked `/dev/dm-5`. But that gives me the error:

```
GRUB failed to install to the following devices:

/dev/dm-5
```

On another grub devices post I found someone asking for the output of `sudo parted -l`, so here's mine: https://gist.github.com/tfountain/e1a56e9d1a76ef2f8406 . Should I be selecting one of the other install devices (one of which I assume is my Windows partition?) Why does the parted output list so many partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit more fiddling I was able to narrow this down to a RAID-related issue with my laptop (which is a Sony Vaio Z). In the end I was able to solve the problem using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), however running this from my existing Ubuntu didn't work - I had to run it from a 'Try Ubuntu' installer. Hopefully this will help someone else one day.